# To delete everything except for words between a start and end point

Tags: vba, ms-word

I happen to have problems trying to manipulate the below code to my liking.
First off, the code below deletes everything in between the start and end conditions I have stipulated in my program.

I would like to change this, to delete everything besides those stipulated between the start and end words.

```vb
Sub SomeSub()
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
    Dim Find1stRange As Range, FindEndRange As Range
    Dim DelRange As Range, DelStartRange As Range, DelEndRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Setting up the Ranges
    Set Find1stRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set FindEndRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set DelRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    'Set your Start and End Find words here to cleanup the script
    StartWord = "From: Research.TA@traditionanalytics.com|Tradition Analytics Commentary| | |"
    EndWord = "This message has been scanned for malware by Websense. www.websense.com"

    'Starting the Find First Word
    With Find1stRange.Find
        .Text = StartWord
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        'Execute the Find
        Do While .Execute
            'If Found then do extra script
            If .Found = True Then
                'Setting the Found range to the DelStartRange
                Set DelStartRange = Find1stRange
                'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                DelStartRange.Select

                'Setting the FindEndRange up for the remainder of the document form the end of the StartWord
                FindEndRange.Start = DelStartRange.End
                FindEndRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

                'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                FindEndRange.Select

                'Setting the Find to look for the End Word
                With FindEndRange.Find
                    .Text = EndWord
                    .Execute

                    'If Found then do extra script
                    If .Found = True Then
                        'Setting the Found range to the DelEndRange
                        Set DelEndRange = FindEndRange

                        'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                        DelEndRange.Select

                    End If
                End With

                'Selecting the delete range
                DelRange.Start = DelStartRange.Start
                DelRange.End = DelEndRange.End
                'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                DelRange.Select

                'Remove comment to actually delete
                DelRange.Delete
            End If      'Ending the If Find1stRange .Found = True
        Loop        'Ending the Do While .Execute Loop 
    End With    'Ending the Find1stRange.Find With Statement
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah! That's a new twist  There's certainly more than one way to go about it; my inclination would be to work with (at least) three Ranges. Something like this:

```
Sub FindAndDeleteEverythingElse()
  Dim strFind1 As String, strFind2 As String
  Dim rngDoc As word.Range, rngFind1 As word.Range
  Dim rngFind2 As word.Range
  Dim bFound As Boolean

  strFind1 = "You"
  strFind2 = "directly."
  Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.content
  Set rngFind1 = rngDoc.Duplicate
  Set rngFind2 = rngDoc.Duplicate
  With rngFind1.Find
    .Text = strFind1
    bFound = .Execute
  End With
  If bFound Then
    With rngFind2.Find
        .Text = strFind2
        bFound = .Execute
    End With
    If bFound Then
        rngDoc.End = rngFind1.Start
        rngDoc.Delete
        rngDoc.Start = rngFind2.End
        rngDoc.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
        rngDoc.Delete
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

The "main" Range is that of the entire document: `ActiveDocument.Content`. The Range object is a bit different than other objects, if you set one Range to another it becomes that Range, not a copy. So you need the `Duplicate` method to make a copy of a Range. This lets you use `Find` independently for the various Ranges.

If the first Find is successful, the second one is executed. If that is also successful then the Document Range's end-point is set to the starting point of the successful Find and the content of the Range deleted. The Document Range is then re-defined to start at the end-point of the second found Range and end at the end of the Document, and deleted.

You will probably have to set more Range.Find properties than I did in this code snippet - I used the absolute minimum to make working with the Ranges clearer.

Comment: Hi there, the foundation is perfect, I just need the program to loop through the whole extract and keep all of the start and end parameters. For i.e. I am looking to keep all messages that have the start of To: peter@egoli.co.za and which end with end message.

Comment: I'm assuming we can drop this here (which would be correct) as you appear to have posted "updates" as new questions...?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe another way but till then you can do this.
try to add dummy character after and before your string like this

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .Text = "From: Research.TA@traditionanalytics.com|Tradition Analytics Commentary| | |"
      .Replacement.Text = "From: Research.TA@traditionanalytics.com|Tradition Analytics Commentary| | |######"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      .Text = "This message has been scanned for malware by Websense. www.websense.com"
      .Replacement.Text = "@@@@@@This message has been scanned for malware by Websense. www.websense.com"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Then try to set range between ###### and @@@@@@

this is best answer to set range [select a range of text from one Word document and copy into another Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994590/select-a-range-of-text-from-one-word-document-and-copy-into-another-word-documen)

Please note that in my word 2007 it is not possible to find within hyperlinks. Try to remove all hyperlink or within range before doing replacement.
another best answer for that: [How do you remove hyperlinks from a Microsoft Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091785/how-do-you-remove-hyperlinks-from-a-microsoft-word-document)

Comment: Thanks bud, not 100% what I was looking for, but appreciate the intent to help.